# Error Connecting to SharePoint 2019 via CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom, error, authentication, 2019

We are getting a 403 error when trying to connect to a SharePoint 2019 site via CSOM in one of our environments. The accounts being used have the correct permissions and I am able to connect to the site via PnP PowerShell.

I have compared the .NET Authorization and IIS Authentication settings with the settings in an environment where it is working and they are the same.

I have compared the apps being allowed through the firewall in both environments and can't see any difference. I have also looked at the inbound rules and can't see anything extra in the environment that is working.

Any suggestions?